# Mouse movement lags flash game

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, mouse, games, flash

this was not happening before in a game I play (Realm of the Mad God), which was flash version 11.2.202.621, but now is happening in 11.2.202.626, The game runs through shockwave (swf).

If needed I have footage of the problem.

Problem still persists with flash 11.2.202.632

Edit: using flash player projector debugger from adobe, just recently it stopped the lag, but only for the projector, projector set in 11.2.202.626.

Edit: the problem does not seem to cause lag, but generally stop the game from running in general, data reception and distribution seem to stop when I move my mouse at a high rate.

Edit: This issue might be caused by firefox's cash.

Ubuntu 16.04 was also happening in 14.04.

Comment: You could try playing the game in Google Chrome, which comes with Flash version 22.

Comment: Currently with the version chromium is using, flash has issues maintaining internet stability, as well as input lag.

Comment: Have you tried playing your game in Google Chrome (not Chromium)?

Comment: Same issue as Chromium.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved after I changed the scan frequency of my mouse to 125hz, going through the mouse settings of my razer mouse I changed some of the settings and tested it by playing the game.